# jquery set cookies when a navbar is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to setup a configuration with cookies, using a jquery-cookie plugin.  I want to navigate through a bootstrap navbar and its sub-menus while a navbar is activated.  But the result is buggy, making the navigation impossible.  This is the code what I am using:

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("nav");
switch(cookieValue){
    case "":
        $('a[href="' + '{{path('indexUser')}}' + '"]').parents('li,ul').addClass('active');
        break;
    case "Panel":
        $('a[href="' + '{{path('indexUser')}}' + '"]').parents('li,ul').addClass('active');
        break;
    case "Buyers":
        $('a[href="' + '{{path('companyGetAll' , {companyType: BUYER_TYPE})}}' + '"]').parents('li,ul').addClass('active');
        break;
    case "Providers":
        $('a[href="' + '{{path('companyGetAll' , {companyType: SUPPLIER_TYPE})}}' + '"]').parents('li,ul').addClass('active');
        break;
    case "Categories":
        $('a[href="' + '{{path("nodeBrowse")}}' + '"]').parents('li,ul').addClass('active');
        break;
    case "Configuration":
        $('a[href="' + '{{path('configUsers')}}' + '"]').parents('li,ul').addClass('active');
        break;
}



 $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').on('click', function(e) {
            prenav=$.trim($(this).text());
            navs=prenav.split(" ");
            switch(navs[0]){
            case "Panel":
                delete_cookie("nav");
                $.cookie("nav", "Panel");
                break;
            case "Buyers":
                delete_cookie("nav");
                $.cookie("nav", "Buyers");
                break;
            case "Providers":
                delete_cookie("nav");
                $.cookie("nav", "Providers");
                break;
            case "Categories":
                delete_cookie("nav");
                $.cookie("nav", "Categories");
                break;
            case "Configuration":
                delete_cookie("nav");
                $.cookie("nav", "Configuration");
                break;
            }
        });
```

I need to know why the cookies behavior isn't correct.

Comment: Why you duplicate the same line `var cookieValue = $.cookie("nav");` in every case?

Comment: I fixed my question.